# Pandas reindex dataframe with greater and less than index

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.8

I have a dataframe `df1` as:

```
idx Col1
2   v2
3   v3
4   v4
5   v5
```

I want to reindex df1 for values `df1.reindex([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])` to get the following:

```
idx Col1
1   v2
2   v2
3   v3
4   v4
5   v5
6   v5
```

Where all values less than 2 got the value of index 2, all values higher than 5 got value of index 5 from the dataframe `df1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try notice here I am using the `nearest` with the `sorted`

```
out = df.reindex(sorted([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),method='nearest')
Out[105]: 
    Col1
idx     
1     v2
2     v2
3     v3
4     v4
5     v5
6     v5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`.ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) + [`.bfill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html), as follows:

```
df1 = df1.reindex([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).ffill().bfill()
```

**Data Input:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': {2: 'v2', 3: 'v3', 4: 'v4', 5: 'v5'}}).rename_axis(index='idx')

    Col1
idx     
2     v2
3     v3
4     v4
5     v5
```

**Result:**

```
print(df1)

    Col1
idx     
1     v2
2     v2
3     v3
4     v4
5     v5
6     v5
```

**Edit:**

In case your reindex indices are not in sequence, e.g. `[2, 1, 4, 6, 5, 3]` you can [`.sort_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) first then [`.ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) + [`.bfill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) and reindex again, like below:

```
df1.reindex([2, 1, 4, 6, 5, 3]).sort_index().ffill().bfill().reindex([2, 1, 4, 6, 5, 3])
```

**Result:**

```
    Col1
idx     
2     v2
1     v2
4     v4
6     v5
5     v5
3     v3
```

Comment: This will give incorrect result if you reindex on [2, 1, 4, 6, 5, 3] i.e change the order of the index elements the code above doesn't catch the logic of "greater than 5" and "less than 2"

Comment: @Zanam  In that case, you can use:  `df1.reindex([2, 1, 4, 6, 5, 3]).sort_index().ffill().bfill().reindex([2, 1, 4, 6, 5, 3])`